# Uncheck selected nodes on TreeTable Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treetable

I want to clear (uncheck) selectedNodes from TreeTable. I am nulling selected object but not nulling.How to uncheck selectedNodes?

Comment: To avoid the obvious: are you updating (re-rendering) the view after changing the model?

Comment: Yes. I am updating treetable after clear. But not nulling :-(

Answer (score 0):

press Ctrl and click on the row :)